# Split string into string array of single characters

Tags: c#, string, split

I want to something as simple as turning `"this is a test"` into

```
new string[] {"t","h","i","s"," ","i","s"," ","a"," ","t","e","s","t"}
```

Would I really have to do something like

```
test = "this is a test".Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

edit: To clarify, I don't want a char array, ideally I want an array of string. I don't really see anything wrong with the above code except for the fact that I would think there is an easier way.

Comment: Do you really want each character as a string?

Comment: What is wrong with your code `var test = "this is a test".Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();` ?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
char[] characters = "this is a test".ToCharArray();
```

Comment: Although this isn't what I asked for, I think I'm starting to realize that there really isn't a reason for what I asked.

Comment: @Walkerneo What do you really want? a -1?

Comment: @Walkerneo That's why I answered with this. I couldn't think of a reason you'd want an array of single character strings. No worries though.

Comment: @L.B, Sorry, I updated the post. Didn't realize what I needed.

Comment: @BrandonMoretz I just voted up so that your rep changes from a very nice round number (5000). Thanks for the sharp to the point answer.

Comment: `System.Linq` namespace has extension method `ToArray` which does the exact same thing.

Comment: There is indeed a reason to split into strings: A C# char cannot represent every Unicode code point. For example,  is represented by two chars (surrogate pairs).

Comment: @Fax that is absolutely false. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134002/size-of-char-type-in-c-sharp

Comment: @BrandonMoretz The answer you linked to doesn't contradict what I said? The iterator you'd use to split a string into graphemes, [TextElementEnumerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textelementenumerator), produces strings rather than chars precisely for this reason (and also because of combining marks).

Answer (score 43):

Strings in C# already have a char indexer

```
string test = "this is a test";
Console.WriteLine(test[0]);
```

And...

```
if(test[0] == 't')
  Console.WriteLine("The first letter is 't'");
```

This works too...

```
Console.WriteLine("this is a test"[0]);
```

And this...

```
foreach (char c in "this is a test")
  Console.WriteLine(c);
```

> ***EDIT***:

I noticed the question was updated with regards to char[] arrays.  If you must have a string[] array, here's how you split a string at each character in c#:

```
string[] test = Regex.Split("this is a test", string.Empty);

foreach (string s in test)
{
  Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: +1 for hitting an obvious point that I missed when posting my answer.  Duh.  Why didn't I think of that?

Comment: They have a `char` indexer, and they implement `IEnumerable<char>`, but they're not actually a `char[]` or an `IList<char>`.

Comment: true. they are of type string, but the point is that the developer does not need to use ToCharArray() or any type of conversion to string[] to access the individual characters.

Comment: Mr . @CSharper Me walking the same road now. And It worked for me.

Comment: interesting that Regex.Split treats the string as if there was an empty string before the first and after the last character

Answer (score 8):

Simple!!
one line:

```
 var res = test.Select(x => new string(x, 1)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just use [String.ToCharArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx) and then treat each char as a string in your code.

Here's an example:

```
    foreach (char c in s.ToCharArray())
        Debug.Log("one character ... " +c);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var charArray = "this is a test".ToCharArray().Select(c=>c.ToString());
```

Comment: The `ToCharArray()` seems to be redundant. Also note that you get `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator\`2[System.Char,System.String]` instead of `System.String[]`.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you're looking for the [ToCharArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx) method. However, you will need to do slightly more work if a `string[]` is required, as you noted in your post.

```
    string str = "this is a test.";
    char[] charArray = str.ToCharArray();
    string[] strArray = str.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Edit: If you're worried about the conciseness of the conversion, I suggest you make it into an extension method.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string[] ToStringArray(this string s)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            return null;

        return s.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the message to a character array, then use a for loop to change it to a string

```
string message = "This Is A Test";
string[] result = new string[message.Length];
char[] temp = new char[message.Length];

temp = message.ToCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < message.Length - 1; i++)
{
     result[i] = Convert.ToString(temp[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
string input = "this is a test";
string[] afterSplit = input.Split();

foreach (var word in afterSplit)
    Console.WriteLine(word);
```

**Result:**

```
this
is
a
test
```

Comment: It would be better if you explain it a bit as well. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to meet the "string array of single characters" requirement of the original question.

Comment: This splits it into words, not single characters