# WatiN delay type text between word C#

Tags: c#, watin

I used WatiN to auto text "WatiN" into google search box:

```
using (IE ie = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
{
    ie.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");
    ie.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();
}
```

This code will immediatly type "WatiN" into the textbox and click button ""btnG.

How can I delay between that words, ex: type "W"-> delay for 1sec -> type"a"-> delay for 1 sec-> type "t"...?

Comment: Sorry for the small question... but what type does the TextField method return?

Comment: You can't call a method on `void`... I mean if you removed the TypeText, what type of object would it return?

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about, splitting the string up (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9846973/2051224) then using TypeText to add each character to the TextField.  You could Thread.Sleep(1000) to pause between each character?

```
    char[] characters = "WatiN".ToCharArray();

    foreach(var character in characters)
    {
        ie.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText(character);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a timer to your control and on timer elapsed event update the text of your textfield

like on first elapsed event you write w.... then in second you write wa.... and so on.

Comment: it doesn't work, when it find the textbox and type a new word, the old word will be replace.

Comment: that is why i said you write w the first time and in second elapsed event you write wa... (Old character + 1 new character)

Comment: thank you, but I actually want it type only one word for one time. I wonder if can I use some loops and use a pointer to define the position of a new word