# c# split a string by nothing

Tags: c#, split

I want to split a string which is "00608436483" into every single number

```
minArray = hoursMin[1].Split('');
min = Convert.ToInt32(minArray[0]);
```

`hoursMin[1]` is `00608436483`

I want that i got an array ->

```
array[0] = 0
array[1] = 0
array[2] = 6
array[3] = 0
array[4] = 8
```

...

for example

Comment: What do you mean by "into every single number"? Would `ToCharArray` work for you? It's not clear what you're really trying to achieve here - if you give us more information, we may well be able to recommend a better approach.

Comment: A `char` can't be empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string into string array of single characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846948/split-string-into-string-array-of-single-characters)

Comment: Is the question to split a string by nothing so you get each character or to get the numeric value for each character in a string? I answered the former but got downvoted to oblivion (obviously other people are mind-readers)

Comment: A `string` is by definition, already a `char[]` all you need to do is iterate over the items and convert to `int` or whatever. `Convert.ToInt32(hoursMin[1][0]);`

Answer (score 5):

You can get each character from the string and convert that to a number:

```
string s = "1234";
IEnumerable<int> values = s.Select(c => c - '0' /* which is ASCII value 48 */);
```

What this code does:

- It selects every character.
- For each character, it converts the characters ASCII value to the integer representation of it.
- It yields an enumerable you can iterate over.

Comment: what is the `s` in your code?

Comment: suggest `Convert.ToInt32(c)`

Comment: The string containing the values @PascalHuurni

Comment: Doesn't work on char @Pogrindis

Comment: damn this char business

Comment: `((int)c)` is the ASCII value of the character and `48` is `((int)'0')`. So this takes the ASCII value of the character and subtracts the ASCII value of `'0'` to get the integer value the character represents.

Comment: So that is correct, right? @Corak

Comment: @PatrickHofman - yes, just wanted to clarify, where you got the "magic" number `48` from. - I agree with Jens, that maybe `c => c - '0'` is more readable.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thought you meant the answer was wrong in any way. Thanks for clarifying.