# How to split a string after each unique letter

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to split a string keyword chosen by the user into each individual letter. However I cannot say to split after specific letters as it is impossible for me to know what word it will be until the programme is running. I want each individual letter to be stored separately somehow so i can reference these later.

I have so far tried using the .Split method to do this and had no luck as shown in my code.

```
int keyLength = txtKeyword.Text.Length;  // Calculate length of keyword
string KeyCount = txtKeyword.Text;      // Count the characters 
string[] Count3 = KeyCount.Split(char, StringSplitOptions.None);

string[] keywordArray = new string[keyLength];

for (int i = 0; i < keyLength ; i++)
{
    keywordArray[i] = Count3[i];

    listBox1.Items.Add(keywordArray[i]);
}
```

I have an error appearing in the bracket where i have stated "char" not sure why.

Comment: As Compufreak says use .ToCharArray, the error you're getting is because you're trying to pass the Char type into Split and it doesn't expect it - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2 for the overloads available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string into string array of single characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846948/split-string-into-string-array-of-single-characters)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. If you have a "keyword", then its just a string right? No "splitting" is needed - you would just directly access the underlying char array. Do you need to maintain order of the letters? Do you need to remove the duplicates or sort them?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using:

```
char[] charArray = KeyCount.ToCharArray();
```

But your datatype will be `char[]`, not `string[]`

If you really need strings you can do:

```
string[] stringArray = charArray.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: I've tried using this and not really sure as of yet whether i need char or string. How would i then access this array at a later date?

Comment: It's just a normal variable, you access and store it like every other variable, using properties or something similar. You should read up on it by yourself - It's not possible to tell how to do it from the code you provided and it's also not the scope of the initial question.
I edited my answer and removed the var-keyword to make the resulting types more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand well your problem, but it seems too easy for me since I didn't use split at all :

```
char[] splittedText;
string test = "narmin";

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    splittedText = new char[test.Length];
    for (int i =0 ; i<test.Length;i++)
    {
       splittedText[i] = test[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because it expects a `char`, not the type `char`. 
The following would be an exemplary usage of the `Split` method.

```
string KeyCount = "1.2.3.4.5";
string[] Count3 = KeyCount.Split('.');
// Count3 would be ["1","2","3","4","5"] now
// Note how the "." were cut during the Split operation
```

As Compufreak already pointed out you can turn the `string` into a `char[]` by using `ToCharArray()`. 
Here is a more in-depth way of using individual characters of the original `string`:

```
// Get the length of the Keyword (amount of characters in the string)    
int keyLength = txtKeyword.Text.Length; 

// Store the Text of the TextBox in a variable
string keywordString = txtKeyword.Text;

// Turn the string into an array of chars
char[] charArray = keywordString.ToCharArray(); 

// Turn the array of chars into an array of strings
string[] stringArray = charArray.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

There are a few methods on how to access the characters after creating the array:

```
// 1. Iterate through the array with a foreach loop
foreach (char character in charArray)
{
    // Do stuff with the character
    char tempChar = character;
    if (character == 'a')
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}

// 2. Iterate through the array with a for loop
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++)
{
    char tempChar = charArray[i];
}

// 3. Get the character at a specific position (read: index) in the array
char tempChat = charArray[0];

// The string array works exactly the same for all three methods
foreach (string singleString in stringArray)
{
    // Do stuff with the string
    string tempString = singleString;
    if (tempString == "a")
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

But since you can iterate over a `string` as if it were a char array you can do the following. Notice how I'm using `keywordString` and not a new array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < keywordString.Length; i++)
{
    char tempChar = keywordString[i];
}

foreach (char character in keywordString)
{
    // As seen above
}

char singleChar = keywordString[0];
```